# Error while using Devloader for Tomcat 7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I just followed [this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/TYNAMO/Developing+with+Tomcat+and+Eclipse) article, and am getting the following error. Googling hasnt helped so far. Please suggest:

Nov 15, 2012 2:06:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
Nov 15, 2012 2:06:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 15, 2012 2:06:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 15, 2012 2:06:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1569 ms
Nov 15, 2012 2:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 15, 2012 2:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
Nov 15, 2012 2:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/conf/Catalina/localhost/MavenWeb.xml
Nov 15, 2012 2:06:52 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.catalina.loader.DevLoader overrides final method start.()V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:635)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:837)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:387)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1628)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Nov 15, 2012 2:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/conf/Catalina/localhost/MavenWeb.xml
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.catalina.loader.DevLoader overrides final method start.()V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:635)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:837)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:387)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1628)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Nov 15, 2012 2:06:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 15, 2012 2:06:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 15, 2012 2:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 243 ms

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by using version 3.3 of the Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin (http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html#A3).

For this to work DevLoader.jar needs to be in TOMCAT_HOME/lib.

You'll notice in v3.3 of this plugin, there is both a DevLoader.zip and a DevloaderTomcat7.jar.  I copied DevloaderTomcat7.jar over to TOMCAT_HOME/lib and renamed it DevLoader.jar (potentially replacing the existing jar). This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I get too.
As eeuser answered, you should update Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat, copy DevloaderTomcat7.jar and rename to DevLoader.jar.

If file ${appName}.xml is exist, you need to remove it and update context again.

Comment: It should not be a new answer. You can upvote the appropriate answer when you get sufficient reputations.

Comment: I think so, i just updated my answer. This solution is not enough to fix.